# Import Javascript, ES2015

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I am curious if it is possible to import a module directly inside an object. What I mean by that is, we usually have:

```
import myModule from './mymodule';
```

this way I have MyModule as a global variable inside my code. Would be possible to have something like

```
const myObj = {};
myObj.myModule = [add here my module from import]
```

without using some global variables? if it is possible, would be good approach?

Comment: Nope. All you can do is `import * as myObj from …`

Comment: `myModule` is not a variable and it's definitely not more global than `myObj`. So wonder why you bring up scope. And what is to gain from `myObj.myModule`?